# Ember.js converting controller / view architecture to components

Tags: ember.js, components, web-component

I have an existing `DetailController` and `DetailView` in my app that has some pretty complicated UI / data manipulation logic (hotkeys, copy paste, duplication, autocomplete, etc) -- the view sends UI events to the controller; the controller handles the logic.

I want to convert this to an Ember component.

1. Does this basically mean I merge the view and controller into `DetailComponent`? This seems messy and wrong to me.
2. If not, how do I use controllers and views internally within a component? That is, I still want the complete isolation and well-defined public interface of the component, but internally within the component, I'd like to use controllers and views for organization. Is that possible?
3. Is it possible to use `{{render}}`, `{{view}}`, `{{partial}}` within the component template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this basically mean I merge the view and controller into DetailComponent? This seems messy and wrong to me.

Yes that is what it means.

> internally within the component, I'd like to use controllers and views for organization. Is that possible?

So component basically replaces a single view/controller pair. Beyond that a component is just an extension of Ember.View and can be organized just like any other view.

> Is it possible to use {{render}}, {{view}}, {{partial}} within the component template?

Yes. Any of those helpers will work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you point to any resources / discussions about components replacing view/controller pairs? I'm curious about the motivation behind this design.

Comment: To understand the motivation I guess best thing to read is the [custom element spec](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webcomponents/raw-file/tip/spec/custom/index.html) and of course the guides http://emberjs.com/guides/components - beyond that i would just say it sounds from your question like one large component might not be the best solution. Think of components as a way to make a custom html tag - like a date picker or search box with autocomplete - vs. a way to organize application code.